# Intel Compilers: linking a fortran compiled library to main program of C

Tags: c, compiler-construction, makefile, fortran, intel

So I wanted to use a special maths function but couldn't find a C library that had it, however I found an old Fortran library slatec that had implemented it, so in order to use it, I adapted these instructions to my case :http://difdop.polytechnique.fr/wiki/index.php/How_to_Bessel_Functions_in_C

I'm using a makefile to compile, here's an extract of its contents in the GNU case

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -O2
CC=gcc
MPICC=mpicc -DDEBUG_INPUT
LIBS=-lm -lgfortran

THIS_DIR=$(shell pwd)

WEAKWEAK_OBJECTS=manager_weakweak.o worker_weakweak.o bunch_weak.o transform_weak.o cyclic_array.o
WEAKSTRONG_OBJECTS=manager_weakstrong.o worker_weakstrong.o bunch_strong.o fbi_weakstrong.o rw_weakstrong.o
../mbtrack-mpi : ./besselh/libamos.a mbtrack-mpi.o confmpi.o input.o test.o ${WEAKWEAK_OBJECTS} ${WEAKSTRONG_OBJECTS} bunch.o stats.o physic.o statistics.o tracking.o rw_table.o rw_new.o lagrange.o feedback.o nrutil.o
    ${MPICC} $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LIBS) -L$(THIS_DIR)/besselh $(THIS_DIR)/besselh/libamos.a
```

Everything works marvelously with the GNU compilers, but I am currently trying to compile on a cluster that predominantly uses Intel Compilers, and  `-lgfortran` is not found.

I read up in Intel's documentation that using the `-nofor-main` flag should allow the linking to occur, but the compiler just complains about a linking error:

```
    cc -DDEBUG_INPUT -Wall -O2  -I/opt/local/include besselh/libamos.a mbtrack-mpi.o 
 confmpi.o input.o test.o manager_weakweak.o worker_weakweak.o bunch_weak.o 
 transform_weak.o cyclic_array.o manager_weakstrong.o worker_weakstrong.o 
 bunch_strong.o fbi_weakstrong.o rw_weakstrong.o bunch.o stats.o physic.o statistics.o 
 tracking.o rw_table.o rw_new.o lagrange.o feedback.o nrutil.o -o ../mbtrack-mpi -lm -
 lifcore -lifcoremt  -L/global/u1/j/jackb/work/new_rw_2/src/besselh 
 /global/u1/j/jackb/work/new_rw_2/src/besselh/libamos.a

/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.2.144/compiler/lib/intel64/libifcore.a(for_main.o): dans la fonction « main »:

for_main.c:(.text+0x54): référence indéfinie vers « MAIN__ »
/usr/bin/ld: erreurs de lien trouvés, destruction de l'exécutable « ../mbtrack-mpi »
make: *** [../mbtrack-mpi] Erreur 1
```

I was wondering if there was anything as simple as the -lgfortran library flag that I used with the GNU compilers?

In an attempt to adapt the compilers on the cluster:

Here is the rule to compile the library:

```
   ./besselh/libamos.a : FORCE
               cd besselh/; $(MAKE) libamos.a
```

And the contents of the Makefile in the besselh directory:

```
libamos.a: $(files_o)
#       ftn -nofor-main -fdefault-real-8 -fdefault-double-8 -c $(files_f)
        ar cru libamos.a $(files_o)
        ranlib libamos.a

$(files_o): $(files_f)
        ftn -nofor-main -c $(files_f)
clean: 
        rm -f $(files_o)
        rm -f libamos.a
```

Comment: It seems a little perverse to use the Intel Fortran compiler to build Slatec just for Bessel functions; that compiler provides intrinsic routines for Bessel functions.  The Fortran 2008 standard makes Bessel functions part of the language and Intel have already implemented them. If you want a mixed-language solution (personally I think you should take @VladimirF's advice and find a C library) you only need to wrap a line or two of Fortran with *interoperability with C*.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark yes, and so does C99, I will add it to my answer.

Comment: I understand what you say, but I didn't find an implementation of the hankel functions accepting a complex variable, I adapted the instructions on the page I mentioned in the question to specifically get those functions.

Comment: Please add to your question the commands the make used to compile and link the files before it generated the error.

Comment: @Jack Thanks for the Makefile, but please really post rather the actual commands the `make` produced when you ran it.

Comment: I think I've added what you asked for

Comment: @Jack No not at all, I asked for the actual commands it used to call `icc`, `ifort` or whatever compiler.

Comment: @VladimirF I thought I added that above the error message, that is exactly what is printed when I call the make command

Comment: Ok, and how did you compile libamos.h?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58547/discussion-between-jack-and-vladimir-f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want Bessel functions in C, aren't those in the C99 standard enough? http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Special-Functions.html

The correct option to disable the  Fortran specific `main` in Intel Fortran is `-nofor-main`.

`libgfortran` is the Fortran runtime library of gfortran. If you compiled the Fortran subroutines with gfortran and are just calling them from C source compiled with `icc` it should work.

If you are using Intel Fortran, then it of course doesn't have it. It has its own runtime libraries `libifcore` and `libifcoremt`. You should link them via `-lifcore -lifcoremt` or by linking using `ifort` instead of `icc`. But it is quite likely you will not need them.

Finally, it shouldn't be a problem to find a C library. Try the [GNU Scientific Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Bessel-Functions.html). I think the Intel's MKL contains them too.

Comment: Yeah I did look at the GNU library beforehand, but I didn't find an implementation of the Hankel functions with a complex variable. However I just tried adding those flags, but it just gave the same error message.

Comment: Then try to correct `-nofor-main` first, you had it wrong.

Comment: It was a typo in my original message, it is correct in the Makefile

Comment: Include in your question how exactly does the link command look like, not only the error message.

Comment: I've just understood why, I forgot to clean the besselh directory so that it would recompile the library with the new flag. It works perfectly now. Thanks for your help.